# PHP LDAP_Mod_Replace

Tags: php, ldap

Im Trying to change a password from a LDAP User over a PHP Interface with the function ldap_mod_replace. What i am trying right now is that i have a window where i have 2 textfield password and passwordrepeat. By Clicking the save Button the funtion save executes. But now somethings wont work correctly and i have no Idea why.... I don't have to encode the password.

This is the `changeuser` class

```
require_once("define/config.php");

$ds = ldap_connect(LDAP_IP);
$ldap_user  = LDAP_USR;
$ldap_pass = LDAP_PASS;
$dn ="cn=" . $_GET['u'] . ",ou=Users," . LDAP_BASE;
$r = ldap_bind($ds, $ldap_user, $ldap_pass);

if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    echo "save";
    save();
} elseif (isset($_POST['back'])) {
    back();
}

function save()
{
    echo "0";

    $newPassword = $_POST['newPassword'];
    $repeatNewPasword = $_POST['repeatNewPasword'];
    $userdata = array('Users' => $newPassword);

    if ($repeatNewPasword == $newPassword) {
        ldap_mod_replace ($ds, $dn, $userdata);
        echo "Sucess, $ds, $dn, $userdata";
    } else {
        echo "Passwords are different";
    }
}

function back()
{
   echo "back";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- you cant use the variables `$ds`, `$dn` etc. inside your `save()` function
- your `$useradata` array should certainly not use 'Users' as a key but the name of the password field
- changing passwords via ldap depends on your implementation - see http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/347.html
- and very important: please perform some kind of error checking - what values are returned by ldap_mod_replae etc.? are there any php warnings/notices? do you use `ldap_last_error()`?

Answer (score 0):

First thing: `ldap_mod_replace` might fail, therefore you should add some error-handling to it like f.i. so:

```
if ($repeatNewPasword == $newPassword) {
    if (ldap_mod_replace ($ds, $dn, $userdata)) {
        echo "Sucess, $ds, $dn, $userdata";
    } else {
        echo ldap_error();
    }
}
```

That way you will get more info about what goes wrong.

Second: You are trying to replace the password in the attribute named `Users`. Is that correct? If so, you should - even though it can only contain one value - add that one value to an array. Like so:

```
$userdata = array('Users' => array($newPassword));
```

If that doesn't work out, your error-reporting from step one should give you more detailed infos on what went wrong. Feel free to update the question with those informations.

Hope that helps.